# Cannot install Oracle Mobile Framework in JDeveloper 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle12c, oracle-adf-mobile

I tried to install Oracle Mobile Framework in JDeveloper 12c through `Help -> Check updates.`
It successfully downloaded and asked me to restart the IDE to install the downloaded updates.

I continued with `restart` procedure, but Oracle JDeveloper Studio doesn't get started.

After long time, I started IDE manually and tried `Creating New Application -> mobile framework application`, **It doesn't shows.**

Again gone through Checking for updates.. then it's shows  below screen 
[image]

Continued with **NO**. It asks me to restart the IDE again.
[image]

Any other way install Mobile framework??  Or any solution for this??

Comment: Got it.! Download Mobile ADF and its patch updates from Oracle website. Install it through jdeveloper.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
What you need to do is choose 'No' when JDeveloper asks you to restart now. Close JDeveloper yourself and start it up yourself. (Note: It may take some time for JDeveloper to start up so be patient!)

Comment: Tried. But couldn't install it.. Same issue arises

Answer (score 0):

By the time you posted this issue, I don't know if this page was available in this exact format, but now, for the further issues similar with yours, that others may have, check out and download the Jdeveloper 12c with ADF, SOA, Mobile Application Framework and WebLogic Server from here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html